# Get a report of which link of several links to the same other page was pressed in Google Analytics

Tags: google, google-analytics, links, goal-tracking

Is there any way to see via Google Analytics exactly which links were pressed to reach a certain page?

For example say I have Page A and from here 200 users are navigating to page B; I would like to know if they are navigating via a link in one article or another on Page A, the menu bar on page A, etc.

I have set up goals to find out where people were on  my site before they got to page B but I would like to know more in depth details on exactly how they got there.

Comment: You mean [target audience] -> [ UserFlow]? *Might be translated wrong, I use it Dutch*

Comment: this tells me the path between which pages but not which particular links were used on those pages to navigate between them- some pages might have multiple ways to navigate to another page (links in articles, in menus, search bar, etc...)

Comment: [Behaviour] -> [analysis on page] (or site overlay, again, not sure which english term is used

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a way to do that without doing a little extra. I couple of ways I can think of are below:

1) Set up an event for each of the links or use a Link-Click Listener if you use Google Tag Manager. Google Tag Manager will be your best bet if you are trying to track a ton of links. It will help you automate the whole process a bit.

2) Use a Heatmap service such as Crazy Egg or Clicky to give you a quick visual snapshot of what was clicked on the page.

Using Option #1 you will be able to pull a report of triggered events in Google Analytics.

Using Option #2 you will not get data to work with but a simple visual of which link is performing better.

Comment: The Google Analytics heat map doesn't know which of several identical links was the one clicked on any page.  It attributes the clicks on all of them to the first one.

Comment: I was referring to something external like Clicky and CrazyEgg. I will clarify. Thanks

Comment: Yes, other heatmap products can do it.  I'd imagine that the GA heatmap can do better when Enhanced Link Attribution is enabled, but I've never tested it myself.

Comment: To be honest you...Never even heard of this! I will have to give it a shot myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics has a feature called [Enhanced Link Attribution](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2558867?hl=en) that does exactly what you want:

> You can tag your pages to implement an enhanced link-tracking functionality that lets you:
>
> - See separate information for multiple links on a page that all have the same destination. For example, if there are two links on the same page that both lead to the Contact Us page, then you see separate click information for each link.
> - See when one page element has multiple destinations. For example, a Search button on your page is likely to lead to multiple destinations.
> - Track buttons, menus, and actions driven by javascript.

To implement it, you need to add extra code to your Analytics snippet on each of the pages on your site.  You also need to enable it in the Admin settings for your Analytics property. Their help page shows you how to do so.

You also need to then assign unique ids to *each* of the links on your page so that it can distinguish between them in the reporting.